# Performance , VB.NET SQL Dependency's Notifications

Tags: sql, vb.net, performance, dependencies, push

## Ok i have 2 queries that are running SQL Dependecy's to simulate the push - notifications

really my ownly question is why in heck my 2 pieces of code run so much differently ( slower / faster ) then the other

#### here is the fast code (milisecond updates)

```
lbnoes.Text = ""
    'You must stop the dependency before starting a new one.
    'You must start the dependency when creating a new one.
    SqlDependency.Stop(getSQLString())
    SqlDependency.Start(getSQLString())
    Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(getSQLString())
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT test1, test2 FROM dbo.[ztest]"
            cmd.Notification = Nothing
            ' creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
            Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(cmd)
            ' creates an event handler for the notification of data changes in the database
            AddHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange1
            cn.Open()
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    lbnoes.Text = lbnoes.Text & vbCrLf & (dr.GetString(0) & " " & dr.GetString(1))
                    'PopupNotifier1.ContentText = dr.GetString(0) & " " & dr.GetString(1)
                    'PopupNotifier1.Popup()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

#### HERE is the slow code (almost 2 minutes /update or so it seems) it is almost acting like its calling the on changes over and over. - hopefully you can tell me why cause i rather use this piece of code

```
lbnoes.Text = ""
    Try

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim myConString As String = getSQLString()
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        'con.ConnectionString = myConString

        With objcommand
            .Connection = con
            Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT test1, test2 FROM ztest"
            .CommandText = cmdText
        End With
        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        SqlDependency.Stop(getSQLString())
        SqlDependency.Start(getSQLString())
        Dim dep1 As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(objcommand)
        AddHandler dep1.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange1
        con.Open()
        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = objcommand.ExecuteReader
            'This will loop through all returned records 
            While readerObj.Read
                Dim t1 As String = readerObj("test1").ToString
                Dim t2 As String = readerObj("test2").ToString
                lbnoes.Text = lbnoes.Text & vbCrLf & (t1 & " " & t2)
                '                'PopupNotifier1.ContentText = dr.GetString(0) & " " & dr.GetString(1)
                '                'PopupNotifier1.Popup()
            End While
        End Using
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

### Both on Changes are being invoked the same way ( different invoke methods / removehandles ) ...

Please help this confused nub.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not easy to tell without going further in the application code, but it's much more efficient to access the datareader members trough index than trough column names.

Also, maybe the type conversion has something to do..

Comment: wonder if it is just that much faster, i would hate to use another thread just to get the same results ;/ - ( a lag free gui i mean )

Comment: You don't need other thread, just read values from DataReader class using index instead of column names and right typed method for better performance. It's not the same readerObj("test1").ToString than dr.GetString(0).